# jQuery toggle for multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I am trying to make a toggle for multiple elements in jQuery but it not working the plus button when click does not slide toggle the element please help here is the **[link](https://jsfiddle.net/5neyfguz/26/)**

**HTML**

```
        <!-post  begin-- post 4 >
      <div class="col-xs-12 post-card">
        <div class="col-xs-3">

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-7 post-start" >
         hello this is a test caption
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <button class="fa fa-plus plus-icon post-btn11" type="button">+</button>
        </div>

          <div  class="collapse col-xs-12" style="font-size: 16px; color:#646464;">
            <i class="fa fa-comments comment2"></i> <span>10 comments</span><span class="margin-left-10"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
            10 likes</span>

          </div>
        </div>
        <!-post end for post 4-->

        <!-post  begin-- post 5 >
      <div class="col-xs-12 post-card">
        <div class="col-xs-3">

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-7 post-start" >
         This is a test comment
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <button class="fa fa-plus plus-icon post-btn11" type="button" >+</button>
        </div>

          <div id="post-info" class="collapse col-xs-12" style="font-size: 16px; color:#646464;">
            <i class="fa fa-comments comment2"></i> <span>11 comments</span><span class="margin-left-10"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
           13 likes</span>

          </div>
        </div>
        <!-post end for post 5-->
```

**CSS**

```
.post-card {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.fa {
  float: right;

}
.post.info {
  display: none;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".post-btn11").click(function(){
    $(this).siblings(".post-info").slideToggle();
});


});
```

Comment: I have updated your fiddle, go check it, it now works: https://jsfiddle.net/5neyfguz/51/

Answer (score 0):

Totally wrong selector `post-info` is an `id` not a `class`, then `post-info` not siblings of `post-btn11` but it's parent siblings, so the selector should like this:

```
$(".post-btn11").click(function(){
$(this).parent().siblings('#post-info').slideToggle();
});
```

But better use `class` because it should repeat and not unique. Also add this class to first one too.

```
$(".post-btn11").click(function(){
$(this).parent().siblings('.post-info').slideToggle();
});
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5neyfguz/44/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correction to your code. I have also updated your fiddle so go check it out. You had a problem with giving your post-info element an ID. In corrected version I simply add `post-info` as a class name. And also the `.sublings()` function will not work, since you applied it to your button element and it will not find any nested elements in it. So I needed to find a button's parent element first to get on the "same level" with your next post-info element and then simply use `.next()` function

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".post-btn11").click(function(){
        $(this).parent(".col-xs-2").next(".post-info").slideToggle();
    });
  });
```

```css
.post-card {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.fa {
  float: right;
  
}
.post.info {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-post end for post 3-->

                <!-post  begin-- post 4 >
              <div class="col-xs-12 post-card">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                  
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-7 post-start" >
                 hello this is a test caption
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                  <button class="fa fa-plus plus-icon post-btn11" type="button">+</button>
                </div>

                  <div  class="collapse col-xs-12 post-info" style="font-size: 16px; color:#646464;">
                    <i class="fa fa-comments comment2"></i> <span>10 comments</span><span class="margin-left-10"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
                    10 likes</span>

                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-post end for post 4-->

                <!-post  begin-- post 5 >
              <div class="col-xs-12 post-card">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-7 post-start" >
                 This is a test comment
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                  <button class="fa fa-plus plus-icon post-btn11" type="button" >+</button>
                </div>

                  <div class="collapse col-xs-12 post-info" style="font-size: 16px; color:#646464;">
                    <i class="fa fa-comments comment2"></i> <span>11 comments</span><span class="margin-left-10"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
                   13 likes</span>

                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-post end for post 5-->
```